# Arg[0] declaration as default

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I am coding a **server-client java program**. The code was supposed to be running on `command prompt` after server run of java server as:

**Client user**

Where `client` is the name of the user which will be passed to `args[0]`. In order to take care of the situation where user did not pass the username, I want to initiate a name as anonymous. But the following code did not work and keeps giving `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException` error.

```
    if(args == null || args.length == 0)
    {
        args[0] = "anonymous";
    }
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to change an element of an array that's guaranteed to either be `null` or empty.

One way to sidestep this is by using a separate variable:

```
String name = "anonymous";
if (args != null && args.length > 0) {
    name = args[0];
}
// use name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not assign a value to `null`, nor can you assign a value to an array that has length 0. Thus, `args[0] = "anonymous"` will throw an `ArrayOutOfBounds` exception if the `args.length == 0`

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-initialize it.

```
if(args != null && args.length > 0) {
    args = new String[]{"anonymous"};
}
```

Note: Although it solves the issue, I would use @NPE's solution.